# How to obtain a theme by its reference id

Tags: android, android-resources

I need to extract a default value from a theme, BUT NOT from the current theme.

I know that I can get get the attributes from the current theme like this:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Theme currentTheme = context.getTheme();
currentTheme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, typedValue, true);
// result is in: typedValue.data
```

but I need something like:

```
Theme darkTheme = getTheme(R.style.AppTheme.Dark);
```

...
I only need to extract a single value, I do not want to change the current theme.

Comment: Maybe something like `Theme darkTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(), R.style.AppTheme.Dark).getTheme();`. That seems kinda roundabout, but I'm not sure if there's any way to instantiate a `Theme` directly. I'll have to do some digging.

Comment: looks promising, trying it out right now

Comment: works well enough for me, if you put it in an answer, i will accept it

Comment: I'm gonna poke around a little more. I'll let ya know if I find anything more "correct".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any direct way to instantiate or otherwise create `Theme` objects from resources, at least as far as I could find.

The initial suggestion was to create a temporary `ContextThemeWrapper` and get the `Theme` object from that. We wrap the application `Context`, since it won't (shouldn't) have a theme on it already:

```
Theme darkTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme_Dark).getTheme();
```

Then I realized we could do something like:

```
Theme darkTheme = getResources().newTheme();
darkTheme.applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme_Dark, true);
```

It turns out that this is exactly what the `ContextThemeWrapper` solution is doing internally anyway, so this method is obviously preferable, as we're not needlessly creating and discarding a `ContextThemeWrapper` instance.

Note that it doesn't really matter on which `Context` the `getResources()` call is made; ultimately `newTheme()` just returns an empty `Theme`. Also, despite the name (and the general non-interchangeability of styles and themes), `Theme#applyStyle()` actually does take a theme resource ID.