# Android : Getting a color/drawable from anorther theme

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme

I would like to make a theme chooser for my app.
In a recyclerView I want to have items background color based on the theme they represent.
To be more clear, my themes are like this

```
`<style name="blueDragon" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#39a1ff</item>
    <item name="backgroundPrimary">#39a1ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#2F4B75</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#39a1ff</item>
</style>`
```

And each item in the recyclerView has to views which background should be backgroundPrimary and colorPrimaryDark, and this for each theme.

How can I get a color from a theme which is not the current theme ?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976965/how-to-obtain-a-theme-by-its-reference-id) should be of some help to you. The answer shows how to get a specific `Theme`, and the question shows how to resolve an attribute's value in that `Theme`.